# What should be our battle plan for tagging strategy and tactics?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

We have a [**[strategy]**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) tag on the parent site... which is unfortunately mixed between [strategies to use in games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/641/counter-for-korean-war-wagon), and [games of the strategy genre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/680/tower-defense-games-for-ps3). I looked into this because I noticed a new [**[tactic]**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactic) tag, which has less option for confusion (since the corresponding game tag would be something like **[tactical]**), but then brings us into the nice divide between "What is a strategy versus what is a tactic?". I never really knew the difference between a Tactical RPG and a Strategy RPG, myself, they both seemed very much the same.

We need better ways to differentiate a "strategy game" from a "game strategy". It's a bit of a conundrum, because I'm not sure how we should properly categorize different game strategies. Boss strategies are different than level strategies which are different than situational counters, but where do we draw the line between needing individual tags for each of these versus just one general strategy tag? I think we might be able to get by with having a single tag to cover questions about strategic actions in games, but that then brings us to how we can sensibly distinguish it from the genre tag without making it confusing for the end user.

To my understanding, by the way, a "strategy" tends to revolve around a complete plan for solving a situation while a "tactic" is a specific element of action suited to a need. I am possibly wrong, in which case it establishes the confusion that can result from these different tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have changed my opinion. The [strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) tag should be killed with fire. See the [more recent meta-discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1855/the-two-heads-of-janus-strategy-bifrons).

Comment: I like this (now, haha~), in combination with my points about using more useful and segregated terms like [boss-fight] to handle actual strategy questions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've read the decision towards [meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and I fully understand the reasoning behind it BUT (a big one) I would like to find question-answer pairs on Arqade which are about a particular game and are just about 'tactics', just to be able to study on some games I've recently started playing and wanting to improve myself. Right now I have to delve deeper into the said title and first expertise myself with its terms, and then move on finding specific topics on those terms.

If we aren't going to use meta-tags like 'strategy' or 'tactics' here, could we at least try to find another way to filter the tactics questions, or is this a completely waste of energy?

(I've started playing FTL last week, which I've bought 2 years ago, and can't get rid of it now. I could solve some parts of it by myself and so I wanted to learn some tactics by reading questions here but can't filter the questions generally with something like a 'tactics' tag.)

Comment: Hi there! This is a really, really old discussion from long ago, back when our tagging policies differed muchly. While it's not entirely inaccurate, I'd recommend starting a new discussion on this topic to work on how to tag your question and its viability. That would do it more useful justice I feel.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll do it later at night when I have the time.