# The two heads of Janus "Strategy" Bifrons

Tags: discussion, status-completed, ambiguous-tags

Okay, let's start reviewing our bad tags. Currently no one has a clear idea of what [strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) is about; proof is this tag was the [2nd entry in the original version](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/eb440102-aeb3-4d3e-b90b-548ef663a6ad/view-source) of the [excerpt rally](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/top-tags-requiring-a-tag-wiki/1595#1595) and has since then [survived 30 revisions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/36a26eb2-d56b-4919-9462-898c7b45890f/view-source). Yet, it claims 178 questions!

This is probably because the tag is overloaded with two broad meanings:

- Strategy, *as opposed to technique, [or tips, or hints, or how-to, or guide](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/703/guide-strategy-tips-how-to-which-do-i-use)*...
  Example: [What race should I genocide?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17030/what-race-should-i-genocide) (tagged nethack strategy)
- Strategy, *as the game genre, inclusive of turn-based-strategy, real-time-strategy*...
  Example: [How is conflict resolution calculated in Castle Vox?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16186/how-is-conflict-resolution-calculated-in-castle-vox) (tagged pc, strategy, turn-based-strategy, castle-vox)

What should be done about this tag?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus

Comment: The fact that it survived so long without a tag wiki is a very bad sign. I agree with you (and Mana, and Grace) that this tag should be killed with fire.

Comment: @Oak At this point the only thing stopping me is that, as you know, there's no "kill with fire" button we can press on for tags.

Comment: btw @badp killing it with fire might have [interesting consequences](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/194/strategy).

Comment: @Oak  Hoenstly I don't think tzenes likes being the champion of a meaningless tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, not long after the much regrettable death of [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder) as [reported in the obituaries](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/whither-murder), the tag [strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) has been cleaned out from the site.

Comment: Finally that stupid meaningless tag is gone from my top 3 tags on the Users page.

Answer (score 10):

This tag should be removed entirely. The fact that the tag is overloaded with two broad meanings implies that it will continue to be used for these two broad meanings, regardless of what definition we might agree is more appropriate here; not every user will have the patience nor the time to peruse the meta site or know about the tag wiki. Every time I've come across the tag, I've been forced to venture to meta to see if we have some kind of consensus on how it should be used. I should be able to surmise at a glance the definition and approximate usage of a tag; that I am unable to do so with [strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) implies that **it is a poor tag** and that **it should be destroyed. Mercilessly.**

I would use [tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics) for the Nethack question you brought up and for all other questions where strategy is used as a term for plan, not genre. If we wish to continue using a different tag for the genre, we must also take pains towards tagging other games with their genres; the tags [first-person-shooter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-person-shooter) and [rpg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg) are not being used to their full extent, limiting their usefulness. I'll bring up this problem with genre tags in another meta question.

Comment: Honestly I'd kill [tactics] too, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @badp Out of curiosity, why? Just not very useful, or do you have concerns about ambiguity?

Comment: @Mana IMHO it's just part of that family of tags that just say "hey, this post is a question!" like how-to, tips, guide, etc.

Comment: @badp Fair enough; I think Grace shares your opinion on that so those tags might not be long for life.

Comment: right this is a classic meta tag symptom http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the link, I'd forgotten about that one.

Comment: I think we're better off with a bunch of tags that are a lot more explicit than "tactics". It simply doesn't tell you anything because it is so wide and overarching. For example, "boss-fight" tells you it is a question about a strategy to defeat a boss or otherwise do something about a boss. "achievements" tells you it's strategy towards getting an achievement. I think that model serves us a lot better than the highly vague "tactics", "how-to", and similarsuch.

Comment: See also for [using tactics versus strategy](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/841/starcraft-2-strategy-tag-should-actually-many-times-be-tactics-agree), and [the original discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321/what-should-be-our-battle-plan-for-tagging-strategy-and-tactics).

Comment: @Grace That's true, nice point.