# Setting priority for Twitter #hashtags from question tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Sometimes the mechanism that posts tweets seems to be posting the least relevant tag as the Twitter #hashtag.

For Example:

- http://twitter.com/StackGaming/status/113546504408547328
  Can you answer this? Cannot use Keyboard/Mouse? http://t.co/DYaHzJE #pc
  This should use the more relevant #deusexhumanrevolution (like [this tweet](http://twitter.com/StackGaming/status/113093498030395392)) from the [deus-ex-human-revolution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deus-ex-human-revolution) tag.
- http://twitter.com/StackGaming/status/113274700477640704
  Is there a technique to knocking down doors? http://t.co/mvqYHST #xbox360
  Once again the #hashtag offers no context. Knocking down the door in what Xbox 360 game? #deadisland should have risen to the top.

## Proposal

So what I want to propose (relevant to the [game metatag proposal](/questions/1651/make-a-special-tag-class-for-game-tags)) is to add a weight/priority to the tags for tweets and other social media.

So that the most relevant tag to the question is included with the social media post, I propose the following priority based on metatags:

1. [game-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-series)
2. [game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)
3. No meta tag (assumes new game tag)
4. [platform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platform)

   1. Specific platforms, e.g. [ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds), [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360).
   2. Generic platforms, e.g. [pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc), [atari-platforms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atari-platforms).
5. [genre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre) e.g. [first-person-shooter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-person-shooter), [platformer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platformer).
6. [gameplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay) e.g. [item](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/item), [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements), [pacifism](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifism)
7. [company](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/company) e.g. [nintendo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo), [apple](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple).

Comment: Are you suggesting each tag having its own constant weight, or that you apply the weighting of each tag as you tag a question?

Answer (score 5):

The twitter bot uses the same algorithm for choosing the main tag as the website does when deciding what tag to stick at the start of the question: pick the one with the most question count. If that tag is [pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) instead of [deus-ex-human-revolution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deus-ex-human-revolution), it's too bad.

As such this post is kind of a duplicate of other, simpler suggestions for affecting how the main tag is picked, such as [this one.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/allow-tags-to-be-blacklisted-specifically-from-appearing-in-the-html-page-title) I'm afraid this is a bit too complex and site-specific to be adopted, but obviously it's the team who has the last word .

Comment: [tag:pc] is a good example of bigger not being better. Probably the best example on Gaming.SE.

Comment: I think this request could be useful to other SEs, but it would seem to be the most relevant here due to the proliferation of tags about aspects of games vs. actual game tags.

Comment: Yet another reason why the meta tags like `game-mechanics`, `weapons`, `money`, `quests`, `achievements`, etc. are terrible and should be removed