# Twitter user StackGaming needs some common sense

Tags: feature-request, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting priority for Twitter #hashtags from question tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/setting-priority-for-twitter-hashtags-from-question-tags)
>   [Make a special tag class for "game tags".](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/make-a-special-tag-class-for-game-tags)
>   [Allow tags to be blacklisted specifically from appearing in the HTML page title](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/allow-tags-to-be-blacklisted-specifically-from-appearing-in-the-html-page-title)

While it may be earth-shattering to change what tag is first in a page title on the SE website, I would imagine the thing that posts tweets could be a little more pliant.  As [StackGaming](https://twitter.com/#!/StackGaming) insists on posting questions devoid of any context like

> Can you answer this? [What are "additional points" awarded for?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33719/what-are-additional-points-awarded-for) #pc

,

> Can you answer this? [How to skip intro video](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33681/how-to-skip-intro-video) #pc

and

> Can you answer this? [What happened to the book of Earth?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33382/what-happened-to-the-book-of-earth) #story

following it is just irritating.  Can some intelligence be added to it in the form of a giant list of "preferred tags" (read: game tags) to use before the default?

Comment: Nonsensical hashtags are part of the Twitter experience! 

#pumpkins

Comment: This seems to be a subset of the problem of getting preferred tags going across the site in general though.

Comment: @Mana yeah, but to my knowledge, every time that's suggested, it's totally impossible because that's a change to the whole system

Comment: Maintaining such a giant list would be too much pain for too little gain IMO if it's just going to be for the Twitter bot hashtags.

Comment: Tell me if you feel you needed to make this post to propose something different from what's already been proposed in the linked posts and I'll reopen.