# Should we be aiming for more tags on questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we try to encourage at least 2 tags per question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2221/should-we-try-to-encourage-at-least-2-tags-per-question)

When I look around the community, I mostly see questions that only contain a single tag. That tag represents the game the question is about, so it serves to categorize the questions by game.

In comparison to other community sites, it feels like our questions are simply under-tagged.

So, I want you to discuss whether we need more tags beyond the game tag. What do you think?

---

Let me give a few examples of how I think questions could be tagged in a helpful way:

**Is it any use combining Sorcerer's Shoes and void staff?**
league-of-legends, item-usage, character-build

**How to avoid failure and bring back more items home?**
recettear, survivability, item-gathering

**What happened to Steam's second hand game market idea?**
steam, rumours

**How does a Tiki Torch differ from a standard torch?**
terraria, item-comparison

**Does time pass on a Minecraft SMP server if nobody is logged on?**
minecraft, fundamentals

**What are Protoss counter options to Mass Marauder?**
starcraft-2, strategy, survivability

**Can you turn weather off in Minecraft?**
minecraft, climate, mod