# Whither [Murder]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, status-murdered

Where did the [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder) tag go? It appears to have been, well, murdered, silently, in the night, with no record of the deletion in the edits of any of the existing questions.

:(

Comment: I would give this another upvote if I could for badp's extra tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tag has been removed from the site on account that, honestly... it's a pretty bad tag.

Yes, there's a lot of cultural significance to the site. But from a mechanical perspective, especially with a multitude of other problematic tags that we still have ([strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy), [retro-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retro-gaming)) or tags that are just plain messy ([spoiler](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler), [game-mechanics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-mechanics)), it was a poor-quality tag.

Now, there are probably things that one might cite as being more deserving of destruction. But some cleanups are going on, and while it was present, well, it made sense to have it cleaned up.

It may be a damper on spirit, but I think it's better that we have it out of the way so that, among other things, people don't keep countering all discussions about removing bad tags with "What about [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder)?".

At least, keep it out of the way for now.

Comment: The tag was extra fun, and removing it without even discussing it here on meta is yet another very "unfortunate" move of an already poor administration. IIRC many people *favorited* that tag, and that should have been reason enough to keep it, let alone delete it out of the blue!

Comment: @Lohoris If we weren't having countless problems with tagging in general, the Murder tag could've survived under the radars for a little longer. However, I'm sure you'll agree that _fixing the site_ is really much more important than a joke tag :)

Comment: @badp: removing a joke tag is not improving the site nor "making the Internet a better place". That tag *was*. (of course if there were dozens of joke tags I would have agreed with you, but we don't)

Answer (score 4):

The tag has been brought back to life, for a videogame called "Murder". From the tag wiki:

> Murder is a 1983 game by Rabbit Software for the ZX Spectrum.