# What is the strategy-guide tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [strategy-guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy-guide) tag seems to mean a lot of different things to different people, from questions about strategy guides themselves, to questions that are the kind of information you would typically find in a strategy guide, to just general game strategy questions.  Is this a useful tag that just needs a good tag wiki, or a confusing tag that just needs to be removed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The two heads of Janus "Strategy" Bifrons](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1855/the-two-heads-of-janus-strategy-bifrons)

Answer (score 2):

Related: [[guide], [strategy], [tips], [how-to]... which do I use?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/703/guide-strategy-tips-how-to-which-do-i-use), which covered a precursor tags [guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guide) and [walkthrough](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walkthrough). Which probably still exist.

If we retain it, I think its best utility towards existing as a tag is to indicate questions that want a strategy guide from outside. But unlike a full walkthrough, we are capable of and somewhat intended to *be* a strategy guide. We haven't gotten many of these questions for months, now, though, but that remains the main useful utility I can see for it.

Using it to describe questions about strategy or content in guides that we host on our site is redundant with asking it on the site. If you want to find guide-like information for a game on this site, this should be found by browsing the tag for that game, not browsing this kind of tag. That utility is also about the same as tagging it with "strategy", which we seem to agree needs to be destroyed. If something needs to be tagged like that, it should be tagged according to what kind of thing you're asking for - a weapons chart should have [weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons), for example.

There are a lot of questions that use a lot of tags for the purposes described in the previous question. In addition to the [two I](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3504/how-do-i-move-the-boulder-in-the-labyrinth-for-the-game-cave-story) [named above](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12222/stuck-on-the-insanitarium-6-in-skull-room), you'll also see questions with tags like [tips](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips). All of these instances tend to be low in quantity, so it may help for us to prune these down first, then re-examine what's left in order to determine what to do about walkthrough/guide/strategy-guide as tags.

Comment: On a related note, the lack of ability to natively support walkthroughs (something GameFAQs does well) is probably one of our biggest weaknesses.

Comment: @tzenes Fully agreed. I think I remember citing that weakness very early on in the site, but it was probably on a tangent related to game-recs.