# Tags to distinguish tactics/strategy questions

Tags: discussion, tags

Two weeks ago when I was looking for some answers to my question I've came upon this post : [What should be our battle plan for tagging strategy and tactics?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321/)

@Gracenote told me to post a separate question to discuss this old matter one more time. So, here I am:

OK, I've read the decision towards meta-tags and I fully understand the reasoning behind it BUT (a big one) I would like to find question-answer pairs on Arqade which are about a particular game and are just about 'tactics', just to be able to study on some games I've recently started playing and wanting to improve myself. Right now I have to delve deeper into the said title and first expertise myself with its terms, and then move on finding specific topics on those terms.

If we aren't going to use meta-tags like 'strategy' or 'tactics' here, could we at least try to find another way to filter the tactics questions, or is this a completely waste of energy?

(I've started playing FTL last week, which I've bought 2 years ago, and can't get rid of it now. I could solve most of it by myself and so I wanted to learn some tactics by reading questions here but I can't filter the related questions generally with something like a 'tactics' tag.)

Comment: I would note that some of these tags exist, although they aren't ambiguous meta tags - they're specific to the topic/game at hand. See [tag:zerg],[tag:terran],[tag:protoss], or [tag:tf2-scout], [tag:tf2-heavy], [tag:tf2-engineer] etc